# I don't understand て-form + おくれ structure

Tags: grammar, translation, syntax, て-form

I am reading a manga and I happened to read these sentences:

お前さん、**起きておくれよ**。

遅くなるといけないから、早く商いに**行っておくれ**。

What does the structure ～ておくれ mean?